# map pointWidth to a single Datapoint in Column Chart

Tags: anychart

I know i can set the pointWidth ("Bar-width") to a whole series in Anychart.

```
series1.pointWidth(20);
```

Here:[Anychart Documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/8.0.1/Common_Settings/Point_Size)

But how can I map a width to just a single Bar in the series?

[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbAKe.jpg)

I also know I can map other attributes like color already, but no pointWidth:

```
// create a data set
    var data = anychart.data.set([
      ["John", 10000, 12500],
      ["Jake", 12000, 15000],
      ["Peter", 13000, 16500, "#5cd65c", "#009933", null, {enabled: true}],
      ["James", 10000, 13000],
      ["Mary", 9000, 11000]
    ]);

    // map the data
    var seriesData_1 = data.mapAs({x: 0, value: 1, fill: 3, stroke: 5, label: 6});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set point width according to its value, probably [BarMekko chart](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Marimekko_Chart/BarMekko_Chart#quick_start) will meet your requirements. 
But if you want to set point width exactly only for a single one bar in Column chart, please let me know in your next comment.

Comment: Interesting! But unfortunately that won't do the trick. I need a solution to set up the width only for some Bars... :/

Comment: Unfortunately as of October 2017, AnyChart 8.0.1 doesn't provide out-of-the-box method to set point width for a single point. But I may suggest you a code trick how to do it with custom drawer. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/8oxtx1qo/1/ .    Take a look at data array, I marked point as 'large' to let custom drawer recognize which point should be drawn as large. Hope this will help you!